# Doubt in derivation of expectation of sample variance

Tags: statistics, self-learning, expected-value, variance, parameter-estimation

I am studying statistics on my own. Please help me in understanding following

Here in evaluation of Expectation $E[\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}]$, why $\sigma^2$(population variance is treated as constant). What to consider a constant and what as variable, how to differentiate?

My thinking - We donot know population variance $\sigma^2$. So we come up with some sample and calculate its sample variance and try to see that it is closest estimate of population variance. But when we treat $\sigma^2$ as a known constant(it means already known value?), then why again are we calculating sample variance.

pardon me for the silly question.

> another doubt - why in sample variance we are considering $1/(n-1)$ and in population variance $1/n$. When we take sample size n large enough ie., n tends to infinity, does n and n-1 do mean same ?

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) is the answer to your last question.  The use of $n-1$ instead of $n$ is a correction to make the estimator unbiased.

Comment: Do not [cross-post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/477810/119261) please. Decide where you want to ask.